# Using a class instance inside itself

Tags: python

Is it considered bad practice to use a class inside itself?
For instance:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, b=None):
        """
        b  (Foo|None): instance of Foo.
        """
        self.a = 'hello'
        if isinstance(b, Foo):
            print(b.a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's no point in going out of your way to use a class inside itself but if it solves your problem then go for it. For example python's standard library `OrderedDict` has an instance where it uses itself inside it's own definition:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    '''od.__eq__(y) <==> od==y.  Comparison to another OD is order-sensitive
    while comparison to a regular mapping is order-insensitive.

    '''
    if isinstance(other, OrderedDict):
        return len(self)==len(other) and \
               all(_imap(_eq, self.iteritems(), other.iteritems()))
    return dict.__eq__(self, other)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's fine. This is actually a pretty common pattern for implementing something like a tree or linked list node.